# Page header and footer auto hide

Tags: javascript

How to auto-hide page's header and footer, and show it by moving the mouse cursor's over one of them.

Comment: Could you please write in better english?  You're question is unclear, and lacks some punctuation..

Comment: Which header and footer do you mean? The one when printing a page?

Comment: seriouly your question is very vague!!

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery you could do it like this:

http://return-true.com/2010/03/creating-a-slide-up-footer-using-jquery/
Demo here: http://return-true.com/examples/SlidingFooterExample.html

He's done it using onclick, you could easily change it to mouseover.

Answer (score 0):

i am not know what you want but i have a small solution that you need.

hide the header footer after some sec  on page load. and show the header and footer when user mouseover the top or bottom ' spaces where we still omit a object or space [blank area].